# How to use `AnimatedContent` in Jetpack Compose for `TextField`?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I want to use `AnimatedContent` to switch between `TextField` and `Text` components.
I am using `text != null` as `targetState`, such that `Text` is shown when `targetState` is `null`, and `TextField` otherwise.

Following is the implementation:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ViewTest() {
    val durationMillis = 2000
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

    Surface {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            AnimatedContent(
                targetState = text != null,
                label = "",
                transitionSpec = {
                    ContentTransform(
                        targetContentEnter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis)),
                        initialContentExit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis)),
                        sizeTransform = SizeTransform(sizeAnimationSpec = { _, _ -> tween(durationMillis) })
                    )
                }
            ) { show ->
                if (show)
                    TextField(
                        value = text ?: "",
                        onValueChange = { text = it },
                        placeholder = { Text(text = "Search") }
                    )
                else
                    Text(text = "Title")
            }

            AnimatedContent(targetState = text != null, label = "") { show ->
                if (show)
                    IconButton(onClick = { text = null }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Rounded.Clear, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                else
                    IconButton(onClick = { text = "" }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Rounded.Search, contentDescription = null)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when `targetState` is non-empty, and is set to `null` from the `IconButton`, following is the animation:

[image: animation]

I want that the intermediate `placeholder` should not be shown, but I am not able to do that. If I use `targetState = text`, then it doesn't work at all.

How can I transition directly without showing the `placeholder` text "Search"?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using `text` as a way to control show/hide state. Instead, use a separate variable for controlling it, like `isSearchOpen`:

```
var isSearchOpen by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

So then in places where you check for `targetState = text != null` you can simply use `targetState = isSearchOpen`. And on button clicks you change `isSearchOpen` to true or false.

In this way, your component UI state is independent of the value and could be more easily controlled. For example, if you still want to show the text while hiding animation is happening, but reset the text on "Clear" button click (so that search results could be updated on click), you would do something like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ViewTest() {
    val durationMillis = 2000
    var isSearchOpen by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var textForAnimation by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }.also {
        if (isSearchOpen)
            textForAnimation = it.value
    }

    Surface {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            AnimatedContent(
                targetState = isSearchOpen,
                label = "",
                transitionSpec = {
                    ContentTransform(
                        targetContentEnter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis)),
                        initialContentExit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis)),
                        sizeTransform = SizeTransform(sizeAnimationSpec = { _, _ -> tween(durationMillis) })
                    )
                }
            ) { show ->
                if (show)
                    TextField(
                        value = if (isSearchOpen) text else textForAnimation,
                        onValueChange = { text = it },
                        placeholder = { Text(text = "Search") }
                    )
                else
                    Text(text = "Title")
            }

            AnimatedContent(targetState = isSearchOpen, label = "") { show ->
                if (show)
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        isSearchOpen = false
                        text = ""
                    }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Rounded.Clear, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                else
                    IconButton(onClick = { isSearchOpen = true }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Rounded.Search, contentDescription = null)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you only need to not show the placeholder then simply:

```
placeholder = { if (isSearchOpen) Text(text = "Search") }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ViewTest() {
    val durationMillis = 2000
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
    var placeHolderAlpha by remember {
        mutableStateOf(1f)
    }

    Surface {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            AnimatedContent(
                targetState = text != null,
                label = "",
                transitionSpec = {
                    ContentTransform(
                        targetContentEnter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis)),
                        initialContentExit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis)),
                        sizeTransform = SizeTransform(sizeAnimationSpec = { _, _ ->
                            tween(
                                durationMillis
                            )
                        })
                    )
                }
            ) { show ->
                if (show)
                    TextField(
                        value = text ?: "",
                        onValueChange = { text = it },
                        placeholder = {
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier.alpha(placeHolderAlpha),
                                text = "Search"
                            )
                        }
                    )
                else
                    Text(text = "Title")
            }

            AnimatedContent(targetState = text != null, label = "") { show ->
                if (show)
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        text = null
                        placeHolderAlpha = 0f
                    }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Rounded.Clear, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                else
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        text = ""
                        placeHolderAlpha = 1f
                    }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Rounded.Search, contentDescription = null)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this.